# IOS CollectionView footer add Google AdMob

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, admob

How can I add google AdMob in UICollectionView "footer"?

I directly add a UIView in UICollectionReusableView, and I got the error:

> The bannerView outlet from the CollectionViewController to the GADBannerView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

I used the UIView to get AdMob like this:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/quick-start

Are there others way to add google AdMob in CollectionView "footer"?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you need to repeat an AdMob ad in a `UICollectionView` ?  FYI, There is a limit of ads displaying in each view.

Comment: I want to add it in the footer. And I used the view to get AdMob like this : https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/quick-start

Comment: if you want to add AdMob below `UICollectionView`, you should create a view below it and add ads there.

Comment: I add a view below UICollectionView, and I got error. Can you give me an example?

Comment: what kind of error ? Even easier, add that `UIView` in Storyboard ( remember to use Auto Layout )

Comment: I use storyboard and add a UIView to the CollectionView.Then appear this erroe:"The bannerView outlet from the CollectionViewController to the GADBannerView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content."

Comment: You'd better learn from basic how to build a `UICollectionView` in storyboard. Your `IBOutlet`s are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you the problem: *"Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content"*.

Advertising is not allowed to be placed in repeating content views, like collection views, table views, etc.

This is because some ads pay by impression, and in a repeating view the ad may be loaded multiple times causing an impression each time. Ad companies don't like it when you do that because they then have to pay you for false impressions (it's the same as having a webpage with an ad that refreshes itself to try and get more ad revenue).

I know this from my own experience where I placed an ad in a place where it was accidentally clickable by users - I didn't get any complaints from users about its placement, but after Admob noticed how much revenue it generated they limited my earnings rate to 5% of normal and told me it would not be increased again until I moved the advert. So there you have it. Don't place your ads in collection views or table views.

Comment: I want  to add AdMob in the footer. So it will not repeat. But it didn't work.